# Return key in .Net Maui keyboard should hide it or focus should move to the next field on the UI

Tags: .net, maui

I haven't got any good document to follow where it's actually answered. Hope I will get some answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the CommunityToolkit.
You can use:

```
toolkit:SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior.NextElement="{x:Reference NextEntry}"
```

Where toolkit is:

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
```

For the "dismiss keyboard" I think its a bug, because it behaves differently than xamarin. Try disable/enable of the Element.

Here is how to install it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/get-started

Here is how to use it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/set-focus-when-entry-completed-behavior

Comment: Could you plz share an example. I used this line toolkit:SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior.NextElement="{x:Reference NextEntry}"
 as attribute to <Entry/>. It's displaying this "
The attachable property 'NextElement' was not found in type 'SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehaviour"

Comment: Have you installed NuGet Package CommunityToolkit.MAUI? (This is working example from my project.) Here is the documentation, if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/set-focus-when-entry-completed-behavior

Comment: Added links with pictures how to install and use it.

Comment: Can I achieve Done behavior too with this toolkit?

Comment: You have ReturnCommand, that you can bind to your ViewModel.